# $\lambda$ parameter for U3 gate in qiskit Bloch sphere visualisation

Tags: qiskit, bloch-sphere

It is easy to see how $\theta$ (rotation from the positive z-axis) and $\varphi$ (rotation from the positive z-axis) affect the initial state of the qubit when looking at the Bloch sphere but I have been playing around with different $\lambda$ values and can't see a clear transformation. Geometrically, how does lambda transform the state?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. This can help: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9668/what-is-the-lambda-parameter-in-the-u3-gate-used-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda$ is also a rotation around the $z$ axis. However, there is an ordering issue. There's a sequence of $z$-rotation ($\lambda$), $y$-rotation ($\theta$), $z$-rotation ($\varphi$).

Comment: Is it a typo we don't have any x-rotation here?

Comment: no. This question was (implicitly) about the u3 rotation in qiskit, which is essentially a sequence of rotations z-y-z.

Comment: I see, thank you!