# Why are there such different UGate and U3Gate implementations in the Qiskit documentation?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, experimental-realization

The documentation for the new version [Qiskit 0.20.0](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#qiskit-0-20-0) states that:

- [UGate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.UGate.html#ugate) is "Implemented using two X90 pulses on IBM Quantum systems:

$U(θ,ϕ,λ)=RZ(ϕ−π/2)RX(π/2)RZ(π−θ)RX(π/2)RZ(λ−π/2)$"

- [U3Gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U3Gate.html#u3gate) is "Implemented using two X90 pulses on IBM Quantum systems:

$U3(θ,ϕ,λ)=RZ(ϕ)RX(−π/2)RZ(θ)RX(π/2)RZ(λ)$"

It looks like only the latter matches the known [rotation sequence](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11423/12280) for U3:
$z$-rotation ($\lambda$), $y$-rotation ($\theta$), $z$-rotation ($\varphi$)

Although their presentation matrices completely coincide:
$$
\mathrm{U3}=
\mathrm{U}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) & -\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda}\sin(\theta/2) \\
\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2) & \mathrm{e}^{i(\phi+\lambda)}\cos(\theta/2) 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Is this an inaccuracy in the documentation or am I missing something and these gates are actually different?

Just in case, the aforementioned difference stated in the documentation refers to the **hardware** (not software) implementation of these gates on IBM Q systems.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source code then you will see that the `UGate` is defined as an alias for the `U3Gate`. As to why do they need this alias, I do not know for sure. But if I were to hazard a guess, then it would be because in most quantum computing literature, $U$ is used to refer to an arbitrary unitary gate/operator. Since in qiskit `U3Gate` is the most generic single qubit unitary gate, it makes sense to identify it with $U$ from quantum computing literature.

Comment: That's quite right about implementation in source code of Qiskit: in [qelib1.inc](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/qasm/libs/qelib1.inc) the u3 gate (like all the others, except the controlled ones) are defined through the U gate too. 
But this does not say anything about the hardware implementation: in IBM Q separate hardware implementations are used for u3, u2 and u1 gates (despite their definition through the generic U gate).

Comment: @Psanfi I do not understand why you think U3 and U would be implemented separately. I would think one would be implemented in terms of the other at the hardware level, since they are essentially equivalent, granted I do not really know if they are implemented differently at the hardware level. The way I am reading it is that if they are equivalent then they will be implemented in the same way.

Comment: You said: "I do not understand  why you think U3 and U would be implemented separately".
I don't think so, I don't know too what the actual hardware implementation of the U gate is and would it be be implemented separately.
The different hardware implementations of U and U3 gates are written in the documentation, I just want to figure out if this can be believed and if yes, what reason is?

Comment: @Psanfi Could you point out where it is written that they are implemented differently? From your question, I only see that for both the implementation is by "using two X90 pulses on IBM Quantum systems".

Comment: Yes, but then there is a colon, below is a specific implementation for each gate (e.g. for the U gate a specific implementation:
U(θ,ϕ,λ)=RZ(ϕ−π/2)RX(π/2)RZ(π−θ)RX(π/2)RZ(λ−π/2). In my question it was a direct quote from the documentation, enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: When a circuit gets sent to hardware it gets decomposed to the gate Basis set of the respective hardware. In most cases this is U1/U2/U3, so the U gate gets replaced by a U3 gate, since as you mentioned the matrices are the same. Thus in both cases U3 is ran on hardware. This is per se independent of equivalences to RX/RY/RZ decomposition since they may not be native gates on the hardware.

Comment: I will not say about RY (instead RY may be a combination of RX and RZ), but RX and RZ are implemented on IBM Q systems. 
They are implemented by microwave pulses and frame changes respectively.

Comment: The u1, u2, u3 gates are implemented by using low level RX and RZ gates on IBM Q systems, see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.03429.pdf).

Comment: @Psanfi What do you say about u2 decomposion from Qiskit's DeprecationWarning: "The QuantumCircuit.u2 method is deprecated as of 0.16.0. It will be removed no earlier than 3 months after the release date. You can use the general 1-qubit gate QuantumCircuit.u instead: u2(φ,λ) = u(π/2, φ, λ). Alternatively, you can decompose it interms of QuantumCircuit.p and QuantumCircuit.sx: **u2(φ,λ) = p(π/2+φ) sx p(π/2+λ)** (1 pulse on hardware)"? May be other decomposition is more correct, e.g: u2(φ,λ) = p(π/2+φ) sx p(λ-π/2)?

Comment: Yes, your decomposition of U2 looks more correct (up to global phase). If the global phase is important (as in cases like adding control), then a decomposition like this would probably work: p(π/2+φ) rx(π/2) p(λ-π/2)

Comment: Might register a mismatch, otherwise someone will use the wrong decomposition from Qiskit's DeprecationWarning?

Comment: Thanks! I'll write to slack. I almost forgot, in the deprecation warning of the u3 gate, such a decomposition:  **u3(ϴ,φ,λ) = p(φ+π) sx p(ϴ+π) sx p(λ)**  - an equivalent up to global phase as I understand it.

Comment: Fortunately, that deprecation warning has already been fixed! It now states: u2(φ,λ) = p(π/2+φ) sx p(λ-π/2).