# Qiskit UGate - which angles corresponds to which axes

Tags: qiskit

Qiskit documentation for [QuantumCircuit.u(theta, phi, lam, qubit)](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.u.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.u) does not mentions the axis against given angle argument for rotation operation.
It just says `rotation angle of the gate`.

So which angle corresponds to rotation operation along which axis?

Comment: You can check those 2 questions, they discuss in details theta, phi and lambda [1](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9668/what-is-the-lambda-parameter-in-the-u3-gate-used-for?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [2](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9668/what-is-the-lambda-parameter-in-the-u3-gate-used-for?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation page for UGate which shows the matrix representation of the gate with different angles. https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.UGate.html